# Tkinter formatting to two decimal places

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, format, decimal

This is for Python 3.4 version. What I have in the code below works; however I can not get my DoubleVar() formulas to carry a 2 decimal format. How do I set the default value from 0.0 to 0.00 as I am using this for currency.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Change Counter")

ttk.Separator(root).grid(row=3, columnspan=5, sticky="ew")

dollarCoins = tkinter.IntVar()
halfDollars = tkinter.IntVar()
quarters = tkinter.IntVar()
dimes = tkinter.IntVar()
nickels = tkinter.IntVar()
pennies = tkinter.IntVar()

dollarCoinsTotal = tkinter.DoubleVar()
halfDollarTotal = tkinter.DoubleVar()
quartersTotal = tkinter.DoubleVar()
dimesTotal = tkinter.DoubleVar()
nickelsTotal = tkinter.DoubleVar()
penniesTotal = tkinter.DoubleVar()

titleLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Change Counter")
titleLabel.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan = 4)

def Totals():
    dollarCoinsTotal.set (float(dollarCoins.get()))
    halfDollarTotal.set(float(halfDollars.get()* 0.50))
    quartersTotal.set(float(quarters.get()* 0.25))
    dimesTotal.set(float(dimes.get()* 0.10))
    nickelsTotal.set(float(nickels.get()* 0.05))
    penniesTotal.set(float(pennies.get()* 0.01))

titleLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Enter the number of each coin type and hit compute")
titleLabel.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan =4)

dollarCoinsLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Dollar Coins")
dollarCoinsLabel.grid(row=4, column=1, pady= 5)

dollarCoinsEntry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = dollarCoins)
dollarCoinsEntry.grid(row=4, column=2, pady= 5, padx = 10)

halfDollarsLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Half Dollars")
halfDollarsLabel.grid(row=5, column=1, pady= 5, padx = 10)

halfDollarsEntry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = halfDollars)
halfDollarsEntry.grid(row=5, column=2, pady= 5)

quartersLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Quarters")
quartersLabel.grid(row=6, column=1, pady= 5, padx = 10)

quartersEntry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = quarters)
quartersEntry.grid(row=6, column=2, pady= 5)

dimesLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Dimes")
dimesLabel.grid(row=7, column=1, pady= 5, padx = 10)

dimesEntry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = dimes)
dimesEntry.grid(row=7, column=2, pady= 5)

nickelsLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Nickels")
nickelsLabel.grid(row=8, column=1, pady= 5)

nickelsEntry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = nickels)
nickelsEntry.grid(row=8, column=2, pady= 5, padx = 10)

penniesLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Pennies")
penniesLabel.grid(row=9, column=1, pady= 5, padx = 10)

penniesEntry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = pennies)
penniesEntry.grid(row=9, column=2, pady= 5)

dollarCoinsLabelText = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Dollar Coins Value: $")
dollarCoinsLabelText.grid(row=4, column=3, pady= 5, padx = 10)

dollarCoinsLabelValue = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = dollarCoinsTotal)
dollarCoinsLabelValue.grid(row=4, column=4, pady= 5)

halfDollarLabelText = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Half Dollar Value: $")
halfDollarLabelText.grid(row=5, column=3, pady= 5, padx = 10)

halfDollarLabelValue = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = halfDollarTotal)
halfDollarLabelValue.grid(row=5, column=4, pady= 5)

quartersLabelText = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Quarters Value: $")
quartersLabelText.grid(row=6, column=3, pady= 5, padx = 10)

quartersLabelValue = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = quartersTotal)
quartersLabelValue.grid(row=6, column=4, pady= 5)

dimesLabelText = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Dimes Value: $")
dimesLabelText.grid(row=7, column=3, pady= 5, padx = 10)

dimesLabelValue = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = dimesTotal)
dimesLabelValue.grid(row=7, column=4, pady= 5)

nickelsLabelText = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Nickels Value: $")
nickelsLabelText.grid(row=8, column=3, pady= 5, padx = 10)

nickelsLabelValue = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = nickelsTotal)
nickelsLabelValue.grid(row=8, column=4, pady= 5)

penniesLabelText = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Pennies Value: $")
penniesLabelText.grid(row=9, column=3, pady= 5, padx = 10)

penniesLabelValue = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = penniesTotal)
penniesLabelValue.grid(row=9, column=4, pady= 5)

calculateButton = tkinter.Button(root, text = "Compute", command = Totals)
calculateButton.grid(row=10, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is python related but an integer is a whole number whereas a float is a decimal number.

Comment: inkblot you are correct. This is a GUI using Tkinter so I am taking values in Int format and converting them to float amount. The program is designed to take number of coins and give you actual values of coins added together

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.format()`, however your variable will be transformed to string

```
dollars = 99.9                          #<== float value
strDollars = '{:.2f}'.format(dollars)
# strDollars = '99.90'                   <== string value
```

I hope that this helps!

Comment: I need it as one that is a DoubleVar is what I am looking for so I can update the inputs and it will reevaluate on clicking the button.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I came to that worked for what I was trying to do:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Change Counter")

#separator line
ttk.Separator(root).grid(row=2, columnspan=5, sticky="ew")

#Input Integers
dollarCoins = tkinter.IntVar()
halfDollars = tkinter.IntVar()
quarters = tkinter.IntVar()
dimes = tkinter.IntVar()
nickels = tkinter.IntVar()
pennies = tkinter.IntVar()

#Output Floats on right Side
dollarCoinsTotal = tkinter.DoubleVar()
dollarCoinsTotal.set('0.00')
halfDollarTotal = tkinter.DoubleVar()
halfDollarTotal.set('0.00')
quartersTotal = tkinter.DoubleVar()
quartersTotal.set('0.00')
dimesTotal = tkinter.DoubleVar()
dimesTotal.set('0.00')
nickelsTotal = tkinter.DoubleVar()
nickelsTotal.set('0.00')
penniesTotal = tkinter.DoubleVar()
penniesTotal.set('0.00')
allTotal = tkinter.DoubleVar()
allTotal.set('0.00')

#Title Document
titleLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Change Counter", font = "-weight bold")
titleLabel.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan = 4)

#Define Function for Button
#Format to be a floating point number of 2 decimals
def Totals():
    dollarCoinsTotal.set("{:.2f}".format(float(dollarCoins.get())))
    halfDollarTotal.set("{:.2f}".format(float(halfDollars.get()* 0.50)))
    quartersTotal.set("{:.2f}".format(float(quarters.get()* 0.25)))
    dimesTotal.set("{:.2f}".format(float(dimes.get()* 0.10)))
    nickelsTotal.set("{:.2f}".format(float(nickels.get()* 0.05)))
    penniesTotal.set("{:.2f}".format(float(pennies.get()* 0.01)))
    allTotal.set("{:.2f}".format(float(dollarCoinsTotal.get() + halfDollarTotal.get() + quartersTotal.get() + dimesTotal.get() + nickelsTotal.get() + penniesTotal.get())))

#Input statment for user
titleLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Enter the number of each coin type and hit compute", font="-size 11")
titleLabel.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan =4)

#Input Labels for Integers
dollarCoinsLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Dollar Coins")
dollarCoinsLabel.grid(row=4, column=1, pady= 5)

dollarCoinsEntry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = dollarCoins)
dollarCoinsEntry.grid(row=4, column=2, pady= 5, padx = 10)

halfDollarsLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Half Dollars")
halfDollarsLabel.grid(row=5, column=1, pady= 5, padx = 10)

halfDollarsEntry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = halfDollars)
halfDollarsEntry.grid(row=5, column=2, pady= 5)

quartersLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Quarters")
quartersLabel.grid(row=6, column=1, pady= 5, padx = 10)

quartersEntry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = quarters)
quartersEntry.grid(row=6, column=2, pady= 5)

dimesLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Dimes")
dimesLabel.grid(row=7, column=1, pady= 5, padx = 10)

dimesEntry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = dimes)
dimesEntry.grid(row=7, column=2, pady= 5)

nickelsLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Nickels")
nickelsLabel.grid(row=8, column=1, pady= 5)

nickelsEntry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = nickels)
nickelsEntry.grid(row=8, column=2, pady= 5, padx = 10)

penniesLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Pennies")
penniesLabel.grid(row=9, column=1, pady= 5, padx = 10)

penniesEntry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = pennies)
penniesEntry.grid(row=9, column=2, pady= 5)

#Output Labels for DoubleVars
dollarCoinsLabelText = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Dollar Coins Value: $")
dollarCoinsLabelText.grid(row=4, column=3, pady= 5, padx = 10)

dollarCoinsLabelValue = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = dollarCoinsTotal)
dollarCoinsLabelValue.grid(row=4, column=4, pady= 5)

halfDollarLabelText = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Half Dollar Value: $")
halfDollarLabelText.grid(row=5, column=3, pady= 5, padx = 10)

halfDollarLabelValue = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = halfDollarTotal)
halfDollarLabelValue.grid(row=5, column=4, pady= 5)

quartersLabelText = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Quarters Value: $")
quartersLabelText.grid(row=6, column=3, pady= 5, padx = 10)

quartersLabelValue = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = quartersTotal)
quartersLabelValue.grid(row=6, column=4, pady= 5)

dimesLabelText = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Dimes Value: $")
dimesLabelText.grid(row=7, column=3, pady= 5, padx = 10)

dimesLabelValue = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = dimesTotal)
dimesLabelValue.grid(row=7, column=4, pady= 5)

nickelsLabelText = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Nickels Value: $")
nickelsLabelText.grid(row=8, column=3, pady= 5, padx = 10)

nickelsLabelValue = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = nickelsTotal)
nickelsLabelValue.grid(row=8, column=4, pady= 5)

penniesLabelText = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Pennies Value: $")
penniesLabelText.grid(row=9, column=3, pady= 5, padx = 10)

penniesLabelValue = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = penniesTotal)
penniesLabelValue.grid(row=9, column=4, pady= 5)

allTotalLabelText = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Total Change Value: $", font="-weight bold -size 10", )
allTotalLabelText.grid(row=10, column=3, pady= 5, padx = 10)

allTotalLabelValue = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = allTotal)
allTotalLabelValue.grid(row=10, column=4, pady= 5)

#Button to run calculations
calculateButton = tkinter.Button(root, text = "Compute", relief="raised", fg="red", font="-weight bold", command = Totals)
calculateButton.grid(row=10, column=1, columnspan =2, sticky = "EW", padx=5)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use binary floats for money calculations as decimals values do not convert exactly.  For instance, float(.1) is not really .1.  Either use integer pennies, formatted to strings as dollars, or decimal.Decimals.  I did the former.  The only changes below are the switch from DoubleVar to StringVar, the new form() function and the revision of Totals.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Change Counter")

ttk.Separator(root).grid(row=3, columnspan=5, sticky="ew")

dollarCoins = tkinter.IntVar()
halfDollars = tkinter.IntVar()
quarters = tkinter.IntVar()
dimes = tkinter.IntVar()
nickels = tkinter.IntVar()
pennies = tkinter.IntVar()

dollarCoinsTotal = tkinter.StringVar()
halfDollarTotal = tkinter.StringVar()
quartersTotal = tkinter.StringVar()
dimesTotal = tkinter.StringVar()
nickelsTotal = tkinter.StringVar()
penniesTotal = tkinter.StringVar()

titleLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Change Counter")
titleLabel.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan = 4)

def form(pennies):
    return '{:d}.{:02d}'.format(*divmod(pennies, 100))

def Totals():
    dollarCoinsTotal.set (form(dollarCoins.get() * 100))
    halfDollarTotal.set(form(halfDollars.get() * 50))
    quartersTotal.set(form(quarters.get() * 25))
    dimesTotal.set(form(dimes.get() * 10))
    nickelsTotal.set(form(nickels.get() * 5))
    penniesTotal.set(form(pennies.get() * 1))

titleLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Enter the number of each coin type and hit compute")
titleLabel.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan =4)

dollarCoinsLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Dollar Coins")
dollarCoinsLabel.grid(row=4, column=1, pady= 5)

dollarCoinsEntry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = dollarCoins)
dollarCoinsEntry.grid(row=4, column=2, pady= 5, padx = 10)

halfDollarsLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Half Dollars")
halfDollarsLabel.grid(row=5, column=1, pady= 5, padx = 10)

halfDollarsEntry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = halfDollars)
halfDollarsEntry.grid(row=5, column=2, pady= 5)

quartersLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Quarters")
quartersLabel.grid(row=6, column=1, pady= 5, padx = 10)

quartersEntry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = quarters)
quartersEntry.grid(row=6, column=2, pady= 5)

dimesLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Dimes")
dimesLabel.grid(row=7, column=1, pady= 5, padx = 10)

dimesEntry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = dimes)
dimesEntry.grid(row=7, column=2, pady= 5)

nickelsLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Nickels")
nickelsLabel.grid(row=8, column=1, pady= 5)

nickelsEntry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = nickels)
nickelsEntry.grid(row=8, column=2, pady= 5, padx = 10)

penniesLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Pennies")
penniesLabel.grid(row=9, column=1, pady= 5, padx = 10)

penniesEntry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = pennies)
penniesEntry.grid(row=9, column=2, pady= 5)

dollarCoinsLabelText = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Dollar Coins Value: $")
dollarCoinsLabelText.grid(row=4, column=3, pady= 5, padx = 10)

dollarCoinsLabelValue = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = dollarCoinsTotal)
dollarCoinsLabelValue.grid(row=4, column=4, pady= 5)

halfDollarLabelText = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Half Dollar Value: $")
halfDollarLabelText.grid(row=5, column=3, pady= 5, padx = 10)

halfDollarLabelValue = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = halfDollarTotal)
halfDollarLabelValue.grid(row=5, column=4, pady= 5)

quartersLabelText = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Quarters Value: $")
quartersLabelText.grid(row=6, column=3, pady= 5, padx = 10)

quartersLabelValue = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = quartersTotal)
quartersLabelValue.grid(row=6, column=4, pady= 5)

dimesLabelText = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Dimes Value: $")
dimesLabelText.grid(row=7, column=3, pady= 5, padx = 10)

dimesLabelValue = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = dimesTotal)
dimesLabelValue.grid(row=7, column=4, pady= 5)

nickelsLabelText = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Nickels Value: $")
nickelsLabelText.grid(row=8, column=3, pady= 5, padx = 10)

nickelsLabelValue = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = nickelsTotal)
nickelsLabelValue.grid(row=8, column=4, pady= 5)

penniesLabelText = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Pennies Value: $")
penniesLabelText.grid(row=9, column=3, pady= 5, padx = 10)

penniesLabelValue = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = penniesTotal)
penniesLabelValue.grid(row=9, column=4, pady= 5)

calculateButton = tkinter.Button(root, text = "Compute", command = Totals)
calculateButton.grid(row=10, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

The excessive duplication screams out for refactoring of some sort, but I leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: This is the solution I came to: